# How can I set a button's tag equal to an integer with Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, uibutton

I have used `arc4random()` to generate a random number and I would like to compare that number to the number each `UIButton` as they are pressed. I have set each button's `tag` equal to the number it represents.

I generated a random number 1-9 excluding 5:

```
- (NSInteger)winningNumber {
    do{
        _winningNumber = arc4random() %10 +1;
    }
    while (_winningNumber ==5);
    return _winningNumber;
}
```

I have `UIButton` 1-4 and 5-9 which are tagged accordingly. When I push a button I want to use that button's tag to the random number.

Comment: OK, what is your question? Perhaps you should update your question with some relevant code. Explain where you need help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get tag value on IBAction method of the Button. Here you can access/modify the tag value:

```
- (IBAction)btnPressed:(id)sender
{
   UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
   NSInteger tagValue = button.tag;

   //here you can assign new tag value to this button as well
   button.tag =  [self winningNumber];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would call something like this from your button:

```
- (int)getNumberFromButton:(UIButton *)button
{
  return (int)button.tag;
}
```

Your button would be setup similar to this (you might use IB to achieve a similar thing)

```
UIButton *exampleButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
exampleButton.tag = 1;

    [exampleButton addTarget:self
                      action:@selector(getNumberFromButton:)
            forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```